# Basic auth for request not taking credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication

Let me start by saying that I did not design this authentication system. I am not a fan.

The way it works is based off of whether or not an image on a separate server can be loaded. So let me break the authentication flow down.

> 1. I want to go to server.com
> 2. If not logged in redirects me to https://authserver.com
> 3. The code for https://authserver.com loads an image and if the image can't be loaded then it will prompt for a **Basic Authentication** window to load the image
> 4. Whenever the image loads it redirects back to server.com

I am trying to automatically access an XML feed that is hosted on server.com. The code I am using as of right now is:

```
  CredentialCache mCache = new CredentialCache();
    mCache.Add(new Uri("https://authserver.com"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(mUsername, mPassword));

    string mUrl = "http://server.com";

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(mUrl));
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
    req.Credentials = mCache;

    WebResponse mResponse = req.GetResponse();

    string strResponse = new StreamReader(mResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

The only output I receive is the source code for the authentication page. This is the code that I am referring to:

```
    <body>
          <script language="Javascript">
                var u = "https://authserver.com/login&redirect=http://server.com"

                function loaded () {
                      self.setTimeout('location.href=u' , 0);
                }

                function noLoad () {
                      theUrl = theUrl.replace(/^https/, "http")
                      self.setTimeout('location.href=u' , 0);
                }                       
          </script>         

          <p>
          <img src="https://authserver.com/image.gif"
                onLoad="loaded()" onError="noload()" onAbort="noload()" />

    </body>
```

So it seems that I just need to successfully get a Basic authorization header for https://authserver.com/login and then it will redirect me to the server, but the C# code I am using isn't working. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the network session from the browser? I would imagine that you need to find the url that is causing the credential popup in the browser. Then, authenticate to that url using webrequest, with a cookiecontainer initialized ( if the successful authentication results in a cookie). Then, subsequently navigating to server.com with the same cookie container should result in a successful response. Or, if successful authentication on authserver.com results in a redirect to server.com with some special token in the url, that should work too.